# How to install rabbitmq on CentOS6

Tags: centos, rabbitmq, erlang

When I try to install the rabbitMQ, I recive this message:

```
warning: rabbitmq-server-3.8.5-1.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 6026dfca: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        erlang >= 21.3 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.8.5-1.el6.noarch
```

My version this erlang is "R16B03-1", because the versioning type for CentOS is different.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error message indicates, you need to install newer version of erlang.

Check the https://www.erlang.org/downloads/R16B03-1, and find an appropriate one.